# Android Flavour dont work correctly

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add two flavours to my android project. Android Studio (IntelliJ) can recognize the flavour folders. But it is unable to behave properly. I tested by changing an image on one of the flavours. But it still grabbed the image from the main folder. So it ignored the flavour option.

So i am doing something wrong. Here is a snippet of my gradle build file. I would guess that i build up the project wrong with the sourceSets. But it work properly without the flavour

```
android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    productFlavors {
        taxiFlavour {

        }
        carApplicationFlavour {

        }
    }


    sourceSets {
            main
            {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                resources
                        {
                            srcDir 'src-gen'
                        }
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src-gen']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src-gen']
                res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/', 'src-gen']
            }

        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['tests']
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Edit: gradle update**

> > ```
> >         taxiFlavour
> >         {
> >             res.srcDirs = ['src/taxiFlavour/res']
> >             java.srcDirs = ['src/taxiFlavour/java']
> >         }
> > ```

Comment: Have you included the image in the same drawable folder for both flavors? Are you sure that you are running the correct flavor?

Comment: I set the build-variant to one of the flavour. Just for testing i put the image on all dpi types. But it does not affect my device. 

But what i am maybe doing wrong is in run/debug configuration. Correct me if i am doing it totally wrong but 

**Module: is the project module** 
**Then i have "deploy default apk"**  
**Then i have launch defauly activity ** 
**Then in before launch: gradle aware make **

Comment: Can you post your folder structure? That should be fine for the run configuration.

Comment: I have added an image of my folder structure

Comment: Why the downvote. i am trying to give as much information as possible for my problem.

Comment: What happens if you remove `res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']` from the `sourceSets` closure?

Comment: Create sourceSet for your flavor too, linking to correct resource folder (and other folders) for your flavor

Comment: The project ran normally without it. But it did not change the image of the taxiFlavour buildtype

Comment: You really don't need all the sourceSet configs. This might sound silly, but you use the same name for the images in all the flavors, right?

Comment: yes i use the same image in all the flavors. But different variants for it.

But i added a sourceset like the edited code above. It made no difference for me

Comment: anyone landed for the demo pls check http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/12/android-studio-flavors-demo.html

Comment: Hey i am also facing the same problem did you find any solution ? will be very helpful if you can share it here .